# Stripe Webhooks in Multitenancy

Tags: java, stripe-payments, webhooks, multi-tenant

I'm currently in the process of developing a SaaS application, and I'm utilizing Stripe for payment processing. The nature of my application is subscription-based, meaning customers pay for recurring services. To maintain multi-tenancy, I've implemented a schema-based approach, and each incoming request is identified by a custom tenant attribute known as "x-tenantid." This attribute allows us to differentiate between various API callers and perform database operations specific to their respective tenants.

However, I've encountered a challenge related to Stripe's webhooks. I'm using more than 10 webhooks in my application, but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to include custom headers in these webhook requests. This limitation has prompted me to explore alternative solutions.

One idea I've considered is storing relevant metadata in the Stripe customer records. When a webhook is triggered, I could retrieve this metadata and use it to establish the tenant context for further processing. I'm curious to know if this approach is considered best practice or if there might be a more suitable solution. Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

I thought implementing tenant validation in Stripe webhooks by storing metadata in Stripe customer records. I expected this approach to enable me to establish the tenant context when a webhook is triggered, allowing for multi-tenancy support. However, I'd like to know if this is a recommended practice or if there's a more appropriate solution.

**Edited: My solution**

Flow:
stripe webhook => webhook controller => webhook service

I extract the tenant information from the metadata, and I've implemented a method that sets the tenant context and schema before persisting data within a particular service method in my Java code.

```
private void setTenantContextAndSchema(Customer customer) {
        Map<String, String> metaData = customer.getMetadata();
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(metaData.get("x-tenantid"));

        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.doWork(connection -> {
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                statement.execute("USE " + TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
            }
        });
}
```

I've followed this approach to update distinct schemas for individual customers. While it has successfully addressed the requirements, I welcome any suggestions or feedback on potentially better methods to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Metadata is the best idea in my opinion.

Your initial plan with Webhooks isn't impossible, but has problems:

For one - I believe the limit of Webhook endpoints per Stripe account is 16.

That's not necessarily a problematic limitation, since you might be asking your Landlords to create a Stripe account for their business.
But that would shift the responsibility of setting Webhooks to your Landlords - Stripe doesn't allow you to create Webhook endpoints on behalf of connected accounts.

Your two options would then be:
-Get Landlords to create a Webhook endpoint themselves
-Ask for their Secret API key to do it for them

Incidentally, I believe this is how WooCommerce does things.
The problem with this is that your Landlords will make every mistake imaginable when providing the secret key or setting up webhooks, so I would be on the side of involving them the least.

Which is why I would recommend metadata over Webhooks for this application.